# Strapi Identifier or password invalid

Tags: strapi

I have an author role, i want user with an author role connect to Strapi app for add content for example.

I found `http://localhost:1337/admin/auth/login` for connect to admin panel of Strapi but this for Administrator.

What's url for user with author role ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a UI without the admin features?

Comment: Yes, i want a UI without the admin features @ghosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible since "front-end users" are separated from administrators.
This is a [good read](https://strapi.io/blog/why-we-split-the-management-of-the-admin-users-and-end-users) on the concept of Administrators & front-end users, it will give you a clear understanding on these concepts & answer all your questions.

Custom admin UI is in the [road-map](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/tabs/) under 3 tasks:

> [Administration Menu](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/13-administration-menu)
> [Users, Roles & Permissions](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/8-users-roles-permissions-ce-ee)
> Also - [Field-level permissions](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/63-field-level-permissions)

So maybe by 2021 :)

What you **can** do to limit permissions:

1. Set permissions on the API endpoints by role.
2. Set permissions on the content-manager & content-type-builder plugins.
   ie. Roles & Permissions => author => CONTENT-MANAGER => disable delete etc.
3. [2018 post from Strapi contributor](https://medium.com/@strapi/restricting-permissions-in-strapi-admin-panel-2bb155621c9c) explaining how to hack some solution until the system has this feature.
   It's complex, hacky and has security failures. I still mention it because it's very relevant to the question and some might be interested.